# Example of periodic $f\left(x\right)+xg\left(x\right)$, where f is even function and g is periodic

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let f and g be non-constant functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Let f be even function and g be periodic one.

I need an example of functions f,g such that $f\left(x\right)+xg\left(x\right)$ is periodic. Could you help me, please?

Comment: $f(x)=cos(x)$ and $g(x)=sin(x)/x$.

Comment: $g$ is not periodic in this example.

Comment: No one said anything about $f$ being periodic. So how about $f(x) = x\sin(x)$ and $g(x) = -\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g=-sin(x)$

$f=xsin(x)$

and $ f + xg = 0$

Answer (score 0):

$f\colon x \mapsto - x\sin x + \cos x$ and $g\colon x \mapsto \sin x$. The sum $x\mapsto f(x)+xg(x)$ is $x\mapsto \cos(x)$, which is periodic (with non-trivial period).

Comment: I know that this is your baby. But $g\colon x\in\mathbb{R} \mapsto \sin x$ is ugly notation.

Comment: Yes, it sort of is... but $g(x)$ is a number, not a function — and I cannot write $g+xg$ either, it does not make sense for the same reason. I've spent enough time pointing out to students that there is a difference between a function $f$ and a value $f(x)$ to be quite fussy about it.

Comment: $g(x)=\sin (x)$ and $f(x)=-x\sin x+ \cos x$ are the usual ways of doing this. The only reason to have the $x\in\mathbb R$ is if that is not obvious. Then write $f(x)+xg(x)=\cos(x)$. You don't need all that $\mapsto$ stuff.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews without wanting to enter a debate about taste and personal notations, I differ on the first point. (The domain can be removed instead of ambiguity — I edited my answer this way, but I'm not that keen into giving the definition of a function $g$ by writing $g(x)=\dots$). In any case, this is hardly, as far as I can understand from the guidelines of Math.SE, the basis for a downvote?

Comment: If you prefer to communicate in the way that makes you most comfortable, ignoring what will actually be understood, you will achieve purity and never be understood.

Comment: That, I don't buy. There is a world between a notation that can be or not be liked, but appears in every textbook, and plain obfuscation. You argue that you find it ugly, *not* that you cannot understand it at first sight... (well, in any case, matter of taste, again, I suppose.)

Comment: You could write "$g(x)=\sin x$ for all $x$." I personally would write "$g(x)=\sin x$" and leave the "for all $x$" implicit, though I could add in the words "for all $x$" at the end of the sentence if I wanted or needed to. That said, I think $g:x\mapsto\sin x$ isn't too uncommon or ugly.